# Adjust "Quick Edit" mode column width in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, quick-edit

Are there any work arounds to adjust SharePoint list column width in "Quick Edit" mode?

Comment: This is supported on ListBooster (http://www.spbooster.com/)  which I'm currently evaluating.